# how to select element form list and put it in textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating messaging app, here sender can select name of receiver using auto-suggestion.
I am able to generate names of users who's name match with entered words.
The part where I need help is, when I click on the name, I want the selected name to appear in same textbox and the suggestion box to disappear. The same way it happens in facebook or here at stackoverflow while writing 'Tags' part.
HTML part

```
<input type="text" id="to" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
```

Part in AJAX

```
<div id='list_names'>".ucfirst($fname)." ". ucfirst($lname)."</div>
```

Please help me doing this...Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in the list_names div you get all the suggestions... so... try like this.
Insert the names in a tag (each name) with an onclick event. Like this:

```
     <div id='list_names'><div id='someId' onclick='setName(\'someId\')'>".ucfirst($fname)." ". ucfirst($lname)."</div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function setName(divId)
 {

      document.getElementById('to').value = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;

 }
```

And... that is all.